# Google Maps v3 using only one's own tiles (converting from v2)

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I use GMapImageCutter to generate tiles and js for a collage (custom map). Everything worked just fine but that was v2. I added markers, infowindows, etc and the projection worked just fine. Now I am at a loss to move this simple application to v3. Can someone direct me to a site that uses NO MAPS just its own collection of tiles - in v3? This is the GMapImageCutter js

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html/xml; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta name="author" content="Richard Milton, Centre for Advanced Spatial Analysis (CASA), University College London (UCL)">
    <meta name="description" content="Page automatically created by GMapImageCutter created by CASA">
    <meta name="keywords" content="Google, Maps, Image, Images, Tile, Cutter, GMapImageCutter, GMapCreator">

    <title>Picture Viewer</title>

    <style type="text/css">
    v\:* {
      behavior:url(#default#VML);
    }
    </style>


    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&v=2.x&key=PUTAPIKEYHERE"
            type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[

    var centreLat=0.0;
    var centreLon=0.0;
    var initialZoom=2;
    var imageWraps=false; //SET THIS TO false TO PREVENT THE IMAGE WRAPPING AROUND
    var map; //the GMap2 itself

/////////////////////
//Custom projection
//pass this zoom level count, wrap Boolean
/////////////////////
    function CustomProjection(a,b){

    this.imageDimension=65536;

    this.pixelsPerLonDegree=[];
    this.pixelOrigin=[];
    this.tileBounds=[];
    this.tileSize=256;
    //use original b
    this.isWrapped=b;
    //define a new b
    //why would anyone do this?
    var b=this.tileSize;

    var c=1;
    for(var d=0;d<a;d++){
          var e=b/2;
          this.pixelsPerLonDegree.push(b/360);
          this.pixelOrigin.push(new GPoint(e,e));
          this.tileBounds.push(c);
          b*=2;
          c*=2
        }
    }

    CustomProjection.prototype=new GProjection();

    CustomProjection.prototype.fromLatLngToPixel=function(latlng,zoom){
        var c=Math.round(this.pixelOrigin[zoom].x+latlng.lng()*this.pixelsPerLonDegree[zoom]);
        var d=Math.round(this.pixelOrigin[zoom].y+(-2*latlng.lat())*this.pixelsPerLonDegree[zoom]);
        return new GPoint(c,d)
    };

    CustomProjection.prototype.fromPixelToLatLng=function(pixel,zoom,unbounded){
        var d=(pixel.x-this.pixelOrigin[zoom].x)/this.pixelsPerLonDegree[zoom];
        var e=-0.5*(pixel.y-this.pixelOrigin[zoom].y)/this.pixelsPerLonDegree[zoom];
        return new GLatLng(e,d,unbounded)
    };

    CustomProjection.prototype.tileCheckRange=function(tile,zoom,tilesize){
        var tileBounds=this.tileBounds[zoom];
    if (tile.y<0 || tile.y >= tileBounds) {return false;}
        if (this.isWrapped) {
        if (tile.x<0 || tile.x>=tileBounds) { 
            tile.x = tile.x%tileBounds; 
            if (tile.x < 0) {tile.x+=tileBounds} 
        }
    }
    else { 
            if (tile.x<0 || tile.x>=tileBounds) {return false;}
    }  
    return true;
    }

    CustomProjection.prototype.getWrapWidth=function(zoom) {
        return this.tileBounds[zoom]*this.tileSize;
    }
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    function customGetTileURL(a,b) {
      //converts tile x,y into keyhole string

      var c=Math.pow(2,b);

        var d=a.x;
        var e=a.y;
        var f="t";
        for(var g=0;g<b;g++){
            c=c/2;
            if(e<c){
                if(d<c){f+="q"}
                else{f+="r";d-=c}
            }
            else{
                if(d<c){f+="t";e-=c}
                else{f+="s";d-=c;e-=c}
            }
        }
        return "sqShelvesFloors03-tiles/"+f+".jpg"
    }


    function getWindowHeight() {
        if (window.self&&self.innerHeight) {
            return self.innerHeight;
        }
        if (document.documentElement&&document.documentElement.clientHeight) {
            return document.documentElement.clientHeight;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    function resizeMapDiv() {
        //Resize the height of the div containing the map.
        //Do not call any map methods here as the resize is called before the map is created.
        var d=document.getElementById("map");
        var offsetTop=0;
        for (var elem=d; elem!=null; elem=elem.offsetParent) {
            offsetTop+=elem.offsetTop;
        }
        var height=getWindowHeight()-offsetTop-16;
        if (height>=0) {
            d.style.height=height+"px";
        }
    }


    function load() {
      if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
        resizeMapDiv();
        //pragmatic extents
        var copyright = new GCopyright(1,
                              new GLatLngBounds(new GLatLng(-90, -180),
                                                new GLatLng(90, 180)),
                              0,
                              "<a href=\"http://www.casa.ucl.ac.uk\">CASA</a>");
        var copyrightCollection = new GCopyrightCollection("GMapImgCutter");
        copyrightCollection.addCopyright(copyright);

        //create a custom picture layer
        var pic_tileLayers = [ new GTileLayer(copyrightCollection , 0, 17)];
        pic_tileLayers[0].getTileUrl = customGetTileURL;
        pic_tileLayers[0].isPng = function() { return false; };
        pic_tileLayers[0].getOpacity = function() { return 1.0; };
        var proj=new CustomProjection(5,imageWraps);
        var pic_customMap = new GMapType(pic_tileLayers, proj, "Pic",
            {maxResolution:4, minResolution:0, errorMessage:"Data not available"});


        //Now create the custom map. Would normally be G_NORMAL_MAP,G_SATELLITE_MAP,G_HYBRID_MAP
        map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"),{mapTypes:[pic_customMap]});
        map.addControl(new GLargeMapControl());
        map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
        map.addControl(new GOverviewMapControl());
        map.enableDoubleClickZoom();
        map.enableContinuousZoom();
        map.enableScrollWheelZoom();
        map.setCenter(new GLatLng(centreLat, centreLon), initialZoom, pic_customMap);

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Add any markers here e.g.
//      map.addOverlay(new GMarker(new GLatLng(x,y)));
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    map.addOverlay(new GMarker(new GLatLng(85,170)));
    map.addOverlay(new GMarker(new GLatLng(85,-170)));
    map.addOverlay(new GMarker(new GLatLng(-85,-170)));
    map.addOverlay(new GMarker(new GLatLng(-85,170)));
      }
    }

    //]]>
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onresize="resizeMapDiv()" onload="load()" onunload="GUnload()">
    <div id="map"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

I made a video walking through how to use MapTiler (from MapTiler.org) to create a tiled v3 map.  http://youtu.be/CeSFUSZLeao  It doesn't quite meet your requirement of using **only** its own tiles, but it might get you close to what you want.

Comment: Trott, thanks for the video but as far as I can tell the results are v2 not v3. Their "beta" is on a web page dated 2008.

Comment: The video explains how to convert the output results to v3.

Comment: Explanation of converting begins at [10:24](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CeSFUSZLeao). If the script fails, try running dos2unix on the script (dos2unix moveTiles.sh)

Answer (score 0):

Everything you need (including examples) is here:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes.html#Projections

It looks like you need both custom projections, and an ImageMapType.

Comment: Thanks plexer. I will forge aheaad.